# Not focusable / not focused EditText with visible caret

Tags: android, android-edittext, widget

I'm writing application with an alternative input method.

I have `TextEdit`, where text comes from external bluetooth device.
The user must see the caret, but it must be impossible to open Android keyboard etc.

Can I have an `EditText` widget with such a behavior?

I have tried to set `android:inputType="none"` but software keyboard still opens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use. This below code. its working me perfectly.

```
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
```

In programmatically use this code

```
editText.setClickable(false);
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: There is one problem. It also disables caret/cursor.

Comment: You can add editText.requestFocus(); programmatically. i thinks it will working for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
} else {
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
}
```

works on api >= 11

Good luck!

Comment: It's not working. My `EditText` is the only `EditText` on this `Activity` and keyboard shows up on start.